# Airplane mode turns on automatically after closing the lid

Tags: 20.04, hp, lid, airplane-mode

I am using an HP 15-da1058TU laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now whenever I close the lid, the airplane mode turns on automatically, and wifi and all services stop working. But I don't want this and want to disable this.